# RDL Expression for NULL date return #Error

Tags: null, report, expression, reportviewer, rdl

Need some help on this, as mentioned above this part trouble me cause it will show the value as #Error if the value of date is NULL.
It's ok if there is a date value but not if NULL. Argghhhhhhh....
I already couple of expression below but none of it solve the issue :

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value), "N/A", DateValue(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value).ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")) 

OR

IIf(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value Is Nothing, "N/A", DateValue(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value).ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")) 

OR

=IIf(Fields!LastReviewDate.IsMissing, "N/A", DateValue(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value).ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy"))
```

Can anyone show me how to solve this? I wish to replace the NULL date with " " or "N/A" or " - "...
This is the output :

[image: Report show value as #Error if date is NULL]

I try to change the properties on my datasource but it giving me this kind of error message :

[image: Error when change datasource properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my issue now, thanks to Uncle G' (Google) for giving me a lot of resources & thanks to everyone who share their knowledge over the internet! Thanks!!!

The answer is :

1) Configure your Expression for the affected column, in my case I need to check if my date type column holding a NULL value or not. This is my example :-

```
=Code.CheckForNull(Fields!LastReviewDate.Value)
```

[image: Step 1, change the expression]

2) Look at Visual Studio menu for your RDL report, select REPORT >>> REPORT PROPERTIES... Go to tab "Code" and put the function for your expression inside, this is my example :-

```
Public Function CheckForNull(ByVal value As Object) As String
    If IsNothing(value) Then
        Return "N/A"
    Else
        Return DateValue(value).ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")
   End If
End Function
```

[image: Got to report properties]

3) Click on OK, Save the solution & test the page where you put your ReportViewer to see the result and BRAVO you just did it right!!!
[image: Enter your function to respond to your report expression column]

[image]